# How to determine when a submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to determine/listen to when a submit button is clicked? I'm using the following and it does not seem to work well.

```
document.getElementById('form1').PC2065$btnNext.onclick = function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none'
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = pTags.length; i--;) {
    var self = pTags[i];
    self.style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

Comment: Submit button is clicked or when the parent form is submitted? What's wrong with your example?

Comment: I wanted it to be the parent form is submitted. When loading the page, I got this javascript console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Comment: I also see this message: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: A Form has an `onsubmit` event.  When you bind to it make sure the document has loaded fully by calling your code in the bodies `onload `event.

Comment: You can use normal Button.And try using onclick() method with javascript.

Comment: Okay, I put it inside this function and it does seemed to work but I still see those errors when the page is loading.

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {
}

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {
document.getElementById('form1').PC2065$btnNext.onclick = function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none'
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = pTags.length; i--;) {
    var self = pTags[i];
    self.style.display = 'none';
}
}
});
```

However, I still receive these two errors during page load.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined 
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.*

Should I be worry about these two errors?